# Size of field extension is at most $p^d$

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field

I have a field extension $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[t]$ and I know that $\alpha ^{p^d} = \alpha$, where $p$ is some prime.

I'm trying to show that then $|\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)|$ is at most $p^d$. I'm struggling on how to get started with this and would appreciate some help. The only fact I can think of is that $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ has size $p^{deg(f)}$. I feel like I may be missing something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: Given the hypothesis, you know that $f(t)$ divides $t^{p^d}-t$. What extension of $\Bbb F_p$ do the roots of the latter polynomial generate?

Comment: Rephrasing Greg's comment and Dilip's answer (both +1) in the hope that it will make you see the light. Do you remember the result that the elements of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ are exactly the zeros of the polynomial $x^{p^n}-x$? If you do, then you are given that $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{p^d}$, right?

Comment: I am aware of that fact, and I can see how that tell sue that $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ but I'm afraid I still cannot see how that helps? Thanks for your help

Comment: So we are adjoining an element of $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ to $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: Since $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$, each $\sum_i a_i\alpha^i \in \mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ is also a member of $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$, and so $\mathbb F(\alpha) \subset \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ which suffices to prove what you are asked. My answer below gives you more than is needed: $|\mathbb F_p(\alpha)| = p^c$ where $c$ is $d$ or a _divisor_ of $d$, instead of just $c \leq d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that

either

- the elements $\alpha, \alpha^p, \alpha^{p^2}, \cdots, \alpha^{p^{d-1}}$ are all distinct,

or

- $\alpha^{p^{c}} = \alpha$ where
  $c$ is some proper divisor of $d$, so that the *sequence* 
  $(\alpha, \alpha^p, \alpha^{p^2}, \cdots, \alpha^{p^{d-1}})$ 
  of length $d$ is $d/c$ repetitions of the sequence
  $(\alpha, \alpha^p, \alpha^{p^2}, \cdots, \alpha^{p^{c-1}})$.

Thus, $f(t)$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $\mathbb F_p[t]$, is 
of degree $d$ or of degree $c$, a divisor of $d$. In either case, $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$
has at most $p^d$ elements.